# Twilio consider space as a character count or not for Programmable Messaging?

Tags: node.js, twilio, twilio-api

I have checked the Twilio document and character limit because I am using Twilio as my SMS Gateway for my Node project.

I'm honestly confused about whether or not SMS messages that have a space and a new line count as characters.

If you have any ideas, kindly share me.

Comment: Can you explain why you are confused or why you would expect that these characters don't count?

Comment: I have check the document of Twilio, It charge according to segments if message is long, In my case I want to send login message with new lines.

Comment: Yes, you will be charged according to the number of segments and yes, you can include line breaks in the the messages. So the number of used segments depends on the full text that you want to send. Tbh, I still don't understand the full question. Can you add the text you want to send to the question?